# Error in a SherlockFragment with WebView

Tags: android, webview, actionbarsherlock, android-webview

Trying to make WebView in a SherlockFragment with the tabbed layout but getting errors. Had working code before but tried to change to onKeyDown would work now get error. Thanks to all. Any help would be awesome. Thanks

Code Java:

```
 WebView myWebView;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_4, container, false);
}

String mURL = "https://www.facebook.com";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("DetailFragment", "onCreate()");

}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    Log.v("DetailFragment", "onActivityCreated()");
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mURL = savedInstanceState.getString("currentURL", "");
    }

    if (!mURL.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        myWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
        myWebView.loadUrl(mURL.trim());
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
        {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )  {
               return  myOnKeyDown(keyCode);
            }
        } );
    }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString("currentURL", mURL);
}

public void setURLContent(String URL) {
    mURL = URL;
}

public void updateURLContent(String URL) {
    mURL = URL;
    myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    myWebView.loadUrl(mURL.trim());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
}

public class WebAppInterface {
    Context mContext;

    /** Instantiate the interface and set the context */
    WebAppInterface(Context fragment_4) {
        mContext = fragment_4;
    }

    /** Show a toast from the web page */
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void showToast(String toast) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("https://www.facebook.com")) {
                // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView
                // load the page
                return false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean myOnKeyDown(int key_code) {
        if ((key_code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}


@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.fragment_4, menu);
    return;
}

 }
```

XML:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/webView"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Error:

```
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054): java.lang.NullPointerException
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at com.bottlecapp.appstest.Fragment_4.onActivityCreated(Fragment_4.java:46)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1486)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:472)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:244)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:531)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
   07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
   07-27 11:29:57.299: E/AndroidRuntime(6054):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1):

the class memember `myWebView` is never initalized. Inside onActivityCreated do:

```
if (!mURL.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    myWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webviewId);
    myWebView.loadUrl(mURL.trim());
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    myWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
}
```

Edit:

Change

```
  myWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.fragment_4);
```

with

```
 myWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
```

Edit2: Inside onActivityCreated

```
getView().setOnKeyListener( new OnKeyListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey( View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event )  {
       return  myOnKeyDown(keyCode);
    }
} );


 public boolean myOnKeyDown(int key_code) {
        if ((key_code == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
                && myWebView.canGoBack()) {
            myWebView.goBack();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: So how would I fix this?

Comment: of course webviewId has to be the id of the webview you put inside your layout

Comment: Now get Error, ill post in question

Comment: did you add the String I had told you in my answer? Post the change you made to the code and the layout as well

Comment: myWebView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webviewId); << This, Yes

Comment: post R.layout.fragment_

Comment: Done, Thanks for helping me again. Posted xml in question

Comment: Thanks so much that worked but the OnKeyDown back button did not work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where do I put that in the onActivityCreated

Comment: after ` (WebView) getView().findViewById`

Comment: Get error on myOnKeyDown Error The method myOnKeyDown(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnKeyListener(){}

Comment: Does that OnKeyDown go in the onActivityCreated and will I not put it in the old place?

Comment: in the old place. add the returns stament

Comment: Get Errors on the return staments Void methods cannot return a value

Comment: what error ? do you changed myOnKeyDown from void to boolean?

Comment: Oh sorry I changed it but still get error on myOnKeyDown in the onActivityCreated, ill update my code

Comment: myOnKeyDown is inside the MyWebViewClient? If yes you have to move it out, in the fragment`s scope

Comment: Oh it was in there but I moved it out and load site but the OnKeyDown does not work

Comment: Like what I want is that if you click a link in a the site then press back button it will go back to the previous page on the website, then if you can't go back anymore it quit the fragment. All it does now is quit the fragment

Comment: witch the return statement inside myOnKeyDown. I edited my answer